# How to split string and fill table - JAVA JSOUP

Tags: java, jsoup

I 'm Trying split the text of this request: `

```
Document document = Jsoup .connect("https://web.servientrega.com/PortalServientrega/WebServicePortal/tracking/api/envio/2003159943/1/es") 
        .validateTLSCertificates(false) 
        .ignoreContentType(true) 
        .get(); System.out.println(document.text());
```

with the result I want to fill a table with the information that I got.
image: [Image with I want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHkDc.png)

Comment: The result is a JSON string. You can decode it to manipulate it more easily. I can recommend you the Google Gson API.

Comment: This looks like JSON response. Are you facing any specific problem which prevents you from continuing writing your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response that page is giving you is in Json format. You need to parse it before you can process it. I would suggest using [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson#google-gson) to parse this response. Currently the latest version of Gson is 2.10.1, which can be downloaded [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.10.1/).

This is a working example that puts the response into a table:

```
String[][] table;
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject obj = parser.parse(document.text()).getAsJsonObject();
JsonArray array = obj.get("movimientos").getAsJsonArray();
table = new String[3][array.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
    JsonObject element = array.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
    table[0][i] = element.get("fechaDatetime").getAsString();
    table[1][i] = element.get("movimiento").getAsString();
    table[2][i] = element.get("ubicacion").getAsString();
}
```

The resulting table looks like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    2018-04-04T18:09:16    |   Guia generada               |   Bogota (Cundinamarca)    |
|    2018-04-05T01:37:00    |   Ingreso al centro logistico |   Bogota (Cundinamarca)    |
|    2018-04-05T20:29:35    |   Salio a ciudad destino      |   Bogota (Cundinamarca)    |
|    2018-04-06T23:52:59    |   Ingreso al centro logistico |   Barranquilla (Atlantico) |
|    2018-04-09T07:50:38    |   En zona de distribucion     |   Barranquilla (Atlantico) |
|    2018-04-09T10:17:36    |   Reportado entregado         |   Barranquilla (Atlantico) |
|    2018-04-09T18:29:54    |   Entrega verificada          |   Barranquilla (Atlantico) |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Baia baia. It's Gson format. INTERESTING!. Thank you.

Comment: @Germán No, it is not Gson *format*. It is JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) format and Gson is simply library (one of many) which can help us parse such structure.